# Finding the IP of a VM in Bridged mode on another VM in bridged mode

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nmap

I am trying to break into a VM (all legal) using another VM. They are both running in Bridged mode. The IP of my VM is 10.0.2.15 so my logic is to run nmap -sn 10.0.2.0/24 to scan my network but I'm obviously wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is too broad, I can't tell you how to solve your problem. However, I'll try to help you understand why your approach may fail.

At first, you need to understand how `nmap` scans a network. You have used `nmap -sn` which means that `nmap` just sends pings (usually) and checks whether they are answered. But what if the other VM just drops those `ICMP` packets? For safety reasons, inbound `ICMP` traffic is blocked by firewall rules on many systems, or is even disabled in the kernel.

There is no general recommendation on how to solve your problem. Personally, I perhaps would start with installing a network sniffer in the first VM, switch into promiscuous mode and try to sniff all traffic. With a bit of luck, you can capture some packets from the second VM (if the second VM communicates with the outside), which will reveal the IP address you are after.

Another idea would be to try [arp-scan](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan). There is a myriad of other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the target VM acquires an IP address via DHCP, most routers will show a list of connected clients and their MAC and IP address.

Failing that, `nmap` has a `-Pn` (no ping) option, which will still scan hosts even if they don't respond to ICMP (ping) commands.

If you know what services are running you can specify the port to scan (eg. `-p80`) or you might want to scan all ports (`-p-`) instead of the default which is the first 1024. I would try something like:

```
nmap -sV -sS -O -Pn -p- 10.0.2.0/24
```

Be aware that bridged mode means this will scan all physical devices on the 10.0.2.X subnet as well - don't do this on your office network for instance.

All this assumes the target VM has acquired an IP address on your network and has services running on open ports. If it has been configured with a static IP you might not be able to find it at all.